# remove specific dictionaries in a list Python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
persons = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'john'},
           {'id': 2, 'name': 'doe'},
           {'id': 3, 'name': 'paul'}]

ids = [1,3]

# remove_persons(persons, ids) --> [{'id': 2, 'name': 'doe'}]
```

I would like to remove dictionaries from a list of id.
What is the most efficient way to go about this programmatically.

Comment: What is your current implementation, and what makes you think it could be more efficient?

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency. Try it yourself first, then ask how it can be improved (if at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the jobs

```
persons = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'john'},
           {'id': 2, 'name': 'doe'},
           {'id': 3, 'name': 'paul'}]

ids = [1, 3]

persons = [person for person in persons if person['id'] not in ids]
```

print(persons)

```
print(persons)
```

but i dont know about the performance

Comment: Changing a list while iterating over it is a classically bad thing to do...

Comment: yeah i agree with you it will create another copy every time if i correct?

Comment: This doesn't ever create a copy, you're mutating the original. The problem is that you dont actually iterate over every item.

Comment: thank for the explanation how about now im changging the answer

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

1. function to delete specific id:

```
def remove_person(persons, person_id):
    return [person for person in persons if person['id'] != person_id]

ids_to_delete = [1,3]
for id in ids_to_delete:
    persons = remove_person(persons, id)

#output
persons
[{'id': 2, 'name': 'doe'}]
```

2. not a function:

```
persons = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'john'},
           {'id': 2, 'name': 'doe'},
           {'id': 3, 'name': 'paul'}]

ids = [1, 3]

persons = [person for person in persons if person['id'] not in ids]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use an index for popping out elements.

```
for i in ids:
    persons.pop(i-1)
```